# Nginx download php files

Tags: php, nginx, php-7

I have nginx and I want to use php within it. my domain is `example.com` and I have a config file for this domain in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/example.com` and this is its config file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    location / {
        root /home/emad/website;
    }

    location /nrm {
        rewrite ^/nrm/(.*)$ /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4646;
    }

    location /files/khu {
        rewrite ^/files/khu/(.*)$ files/khu/$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    }

    location /files {
        rewrite ^/files/(.*)$ files/$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        auth_basic "Restricted Content";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    }
}
```

I change the default config file for serving php files as below like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26163858/nginx-downloads-php):

```
##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls
# http://wiki.nginx.org/QuickStart
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration
#
# Generally, you will want to move this file somewhere, and start with a clean
# file but keep this around for reference. Or just disable in sites-enabled.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

# Default server configuration
#
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /home/emad/website;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /home/emad/website$fastcgi_script_name;
        include         fastcgi_params;
    }
    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }
}


# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#   listen 80;
#   listen [::]:80;
#
#   server_name example.com;
#
#   root /var/www/example.com;
#   index index.html;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}
```

I dont know what should replace with `SCRIPT_FILENAME` in this line:

`fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /var/www$fastcgi_script_name;`
This is also my `/etc/rc.local` file:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
iptables -I FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD -s 10.8.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p udp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 ! -d 10.8.0.0/24 -j SNAT --to 138.201.178.5
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.
/usr/bin/spawn-fcgi -a 127.0.0.1 -p 9000 -u www-data -g www-data -f /usr/bin/php-cgi7.0 -P /var/run/fastcgi-php.pid
exit 0
```

I have `utfw` enabled and now I can see my website firspage correctly but when I enter `example.com/info.php` my browser download php file. I also clear my browser cache.

Comment: You need to have the `location ~ \.php$ { ... }` directive and it's content in the vhost for example.com as well. Every vhost is in their own context, they don't inherit from each other.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson but when I add it to the `example.com` conf file after reloading the page I get `404 Not Found` but the file is in `/home/emad/website/info.php`

Comment: Move `root /home/emad/website;` from the `location /` directive and put it on the same level as `server_name`. You should also add the `index` directive. Again, you need to set _all_ the relevant directives in each vhost/server. Have to ask; when you get 404, are you accessing `example.com` or `example.com/info.php`?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson After that, I change the `root` level everything works correctly.